# How to append and remove an <img > to <div> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Original:

```
<div id="test">
...
</div>
```

After appending:

```
<div id="test">
...
<img src=".." />
</div>
```

After removing:

```
<div id="test">
...
</div>
```

Comment: @Rex M: $('#question-header a.question-hyperlink').text();

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
// add
$("#test").append("<img src='...' />")

// remove
$("#test img:last-child").remove()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('div#test').append('<img src=".."/>');
$('div#test > img').remove();
```

Note that you can give the image a class as well, in case you only want to remove the one you added.